# Ember.js: Handlebars and twig displays nothing

Tags: php, symfony, ember.js, twig, handlebars.js

i am using symfony 2 framework in my project, it include twig.
So i try to use emberjs, so i have problem here.
i try

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{% verbatim %}

{% endverbatim %}
</script>
```

but it still display nothing
Thanks for helping.

Comment: There's nothing in the `verbatim` block.

Comment: yeah, i put some navbar in side and it still nothing :sad:

Comment: here's an example of an ember app, just creating a template wont do anything: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: the problem here, u use twig and it make conflig :sad: